# Help J2me icon problem

Tags: java-me, icons, midlet

I created a j2me application but I cant set an icon it is the default cofeecup icon thats showing. I am using netbeans and I already went to properties and selected the correct midlet icon but it's not showing for the jar file. How can I fix it? Pls it urgent I have a deadline to submit my app.
Note: I have three midlets in the jar file and the icons are showing for these midlets but no icon is showing for the jar file when I install it on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with more then one midlet per jar. Do you want an icon for the complete jar? As far as I remember one can only set icons per midlet - cause those are the one to be shown on the menu of the phone. See [Tutorial about Icons](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1148).

Or do you mean, that after installing the jar, you don't see the midlet icons in the phone menu? For the latter: I remember to have had this issue with some older devices (I believe from Samsung), that didn't show the icons anymore, as soon as the midlet was bigger then a specific file size. Instead the java default symbol was shown, even if the app could be installed and used perfectly fine.

You didn't mention with which phone you are testing, but maybe you could create a minimal dummy project that uses one of the final icons and check if the icon is then shown.

Good luck for the deadline!